# How to execute a script on multiple files using find?

Tags: linux, find, xargs

So basically I need to find a bunch of .csv files then use my script that I wrote on all of them. I have

```bsh
find . -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs ./extractdata
```

this works but only does one file and not all the files I need. Help?

Comment: Does your script expect a single file as the only command line argument, or would it be able to take multiple files as arguments (because this is what happens)?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it did not work is that `xargs` will cram as many files in a command line as it can.

So your "extractdata" script will receive all the files at once, and probably process only the first argument. I.e. you have N files, you execute **one** script with *all* the files as argument.

You need to use the `-n` argument:

```
... | xargs -n 1 ./extractdata
```

This way you have N files, you execute N scripts with *one* file argument each.

However, this is almost exactly the same thing as running `find` with the `-exec` option (one of the differences being that you process the file in found order, while with piping you can e.g. do that after a pass with `sort` and/or `grep`):

```
find ... -exec /path/to/extractdata \{\} \;
```

You might also be able to execute your script in parallel using `parallel`: this executes four instances at a time, **possibly** leading to more efficient processing depending on data, RAM, and hardware:

```
... | parallel -n 1 -j 4 ./extractdata
```

(If "extractdata" uses temporary files with fixed names, which is not a good practice, then two or more scripts executing in parallel will write all over each other's temporary files, messing things up).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the `fd` tool:

```
fd csv -x ./extractdata
```

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve that, for example, you could ask `find` to call the script, like this:

```
 $ find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec your_script {} ;
```

{} is the file name that was found each time.

You might need to escape those chars:

```
 $ find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec your_script \{\} \;
```

Comment: Only the semi colon at the end should need escaping. It would also be good if you could explain _why_ this solves the issue (and what the issue actually is).

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Another question, how could I put everything I find into a new file?